# Laravel ErrorException in c692833c6b3f4dbc2c2d680d56c249ad8685acc2.php

Tags: php, laravel

I suddenly started getting this error:

```
ErrorException in c692833c6b3f4dbc2c2d680d56c249ad8685acc2.php line 16:
Trying to get property of non-object (View: /var/www/html/sudoman281.cz/blog/resources/views/home.blade.php)
in c692833c6b3f4dbc2c2d680d56c249ad8685acc2.php line 16
at CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(ErrorException), '1') in PhpEngine.php line 44
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/var/www/html/sudoman281.cz/blog/storage/framework/views/c692833c6b3f4dbc2c2d680d56c249ad8685acc2.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag))) in CompilerEngine.php line 59
at CompilerEngine->get('/var/www/html/sudoman281.cz/blog/resources/views/home.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag))) in View.php line 147
at View->getContents() in View.php line 118
at View->renderContents() in View.php line 83
at View->render() in Response.php line 53
at Response->setContent(object(View)) in Response.php line 199
at Response->__construct(object(View)) in Router.php line 1030
at Router->prepareResponse(object(Request), object(View)) in Router.php line 704
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 64
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 705
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 678
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 654
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Where is the problem on my server or Laravel? I don't know, what could trigger this, but i did not do anything. Do you know where might be a problem? The project is programmed in Laravel 5.0.

Comment: recompile your code it will remove error

Comment: Could you please post the code around line 16 from the file in question. Its going to be in `storage/framework/views` if you are using L5.

Comment: It may also be useful to post the code from the method that is being used in the controller that loads that page

Answer (score 0):

```
/var/www/html/sudoman281.cz/blog/storage/framework/views/c692833c6b3f4dbc2c2d680d56c249ad8685acc2.php
```

That's a compiled view file.

You can probably open it up and take a look at line 16 and get an idea of what's wrong. (My guess would be you're not passing an object to the view that the view is expecting).

Comment: There is a problem... File with this name doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

There error is coming from your home.blade.php file. There is a cached version of that view file in your storage/framework/views folder with the filename "c692833c6b3f4dbc2c2d680d56c249ad8685acc2.php" and you can see the error on line 16 of that cached view.

It looks like you are trying to reference a property on an object. But that property does not exist. *(For example: you are looping through users and trying to access $user->email and this $user doesn't have an email property for some reason)*

Comment: The error is "Trying to get property of non object" which means in your example the error would be caused by `$user` not being an object, could be an array or string or anything other than an object. Not that email is not a property of it.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Sorry for the sloppy example.

Comment: There is a problem... File with this name doesn't exist.